# Отказывается работать ф-ция unlink()

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

-UTF-8(без BOM);
-сервер Денвер;
-PHP Version 5.3.13; 
-Windows7;

*все файлы находятся в основной директории*

```
    private static $tmp_file= "__tmp__";
    private static $font;

    private static function set_font(){

        self::$font=self::$tmp_file;

        $my_font="...";

        $handle=fopen(self::$font,"w+");
        fwrite($handle,base64_decode($my_font));
        fclose($handle);

        return self::$font;
    }

public static function do(){

        self::set_font();

        ob_start();

        ....

        ob_end_clean();

        unlink(self::$font); /* здесь вообще-то и возникает проблема */
}
```

**Выбрасывает ошибку:

*Warning: unlink(**tmp**) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in ...\www\functions.php on line №***

Сначала я решил что дело в правах на директорию или файл.

Использовал разрешение в **.htaccess**

```
    <Files "__tmp__">
      allow from all
    </Files>
```

Также попытался задать **chmod*(self::$font, 755)*;**
...ничего не изменилось.

Но дело в том, что файл **__tmp__** постоянно используется и занят **httpd.exe**. И я не могу это предотвратить.
Допустим, если перезагрузить сервер и сразу попытаться избавиться от файла, то все работает.

Проверил **fclose**, - работает, возвращает TRUE
Воспользовался ф-цией **file_put_contents**, все равно такая же проблема

Как мне освободить файл **__tmp__**, от постоянной обработки **httpd.exe**? С чего он вообще прицепился?

Comment: IMHO это особенность винды. Нельзя перезаписать или удалить файл, открытый другой программой.

Comment: А почему fclose не закрывает файл так, что бы до Windows-а дошло? И этого можно как-то избежать? Есть еще какой-нибудь вариант закрыть файл?

Comment: Utf-8 (without BOM)
Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3
Win8

Все запустилось.
Использовал dirname(), а то document_root бывает по-разному настроен, и еще интерпретатор ругался на имя метода do()

http://pastebin.com/KkjB2vyh

Comment: (Я попытал счастья с dirname()) unlink указывает точно на файл и он полностью в моей власти, но проблема в том, что он "используеться httpd.exe", и Я не могу его освободить, пока не перезагружу серв и предотвратить его использование тоже. Он кстати весит очень жирно, 228кб

Comment: А предыдущие классы нигде не "хватают" файл не "отпуская" его из процесса?
Попробуйте проверить все моменты работы с этим файлом

Comment: Все проверил, все работающие с фалом ф-ции, - здесь. Закинул этот код на хостинг и все норм работает. Проблема в ОС наверное, надо копаться в настройках сервера. В общем решил использовать tempnam();